# Parsing html string in php using regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I want to parse a html string using php (Simple number matching).

```
<i>1002</i><i>999</i><i>344</i><i>663</i>
```

and I want the result as an array. eg: `[1002,999,344,633,...]`
I tried like this :

```
<?php
    $html="<i>1002</i><i>999</i><i>344</i><i>663</i>";
    if(preg_match_all("/<i>[0-9]*<\/i>/",$html, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER))
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            echo strip_tags($match[0])."<br/>";
        }
?>
```

and I got the exact output which I want.

```
1002
999
344
663
```

But when I try the same code by making a small change in regular expression I'm getting different answer.

Like this:

```
<?php
    $html="<i>1002</i><i>999</i><i>344</i><i>663</i>";
    if(preg_match_all("/<i>.*<\/i>/",$html, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER))
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            echo strip_tags($match[0])."<br/>";
        }
?>
```

Output :

```
1002999344663
```

(The regular expression matched the entire string.)

Now I want to know why I'm getting like this?
What is the difference if use `.*` (zero or more) instead of `[0-9]*` ?

Comment: `*` is greedy by default.

Comment: K. So what is '?' there.

Comment: @VishalVijay: I'll explain that in an answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` in your regex matches *any* character (`[0-9]*` only matches numbers and `</i><i>` isn't a number).  The regex `/<i>.*<\/i>/` matches:

```
<i>1002</i><i>999</i><i>344</i><i>663</i>
^ from here ------------------- to here ^
```

Since, the whole string is inside `<i></i>`.

This is because `*` is greedy.  It takes the *max* amount of characters it can match.

To fix your problem, you need to use `.*?`.  This makes it takes the *minimum* amount of characters it can match.

The regex `/<i>.*?<\/i>/` will work as you want.